# cudaMallocPitch and cudaMemcpy2D

Tags: c++, cuda

I have an error when transfering C++ 2D array into CUDA 1D array.
Let me show my source code.

```
int main(void)
{
      float h_arr[1024][256];
      float *d_arr;

      // --- Some codes to populate h_arr

      // --- cudaMallocPitch
      size_t pitch;
      cudaMallocPitch((void**)&d_arr, &pitch, 256, 1024);

      // --- Copy array to device
      cudaMemcpy2D(d_arr, pitch, h_arr, 256, 256, 1024, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

I tried to run the code, but it pops up an error.

How to use `cudaMallocPitch()` and `cudaMemcpy2D()` properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The  `cudaMallocPitch` call you have written looks ok, but this:

```
  cudaMemcpy2D(d_arr, pitch, h_arr, 256, 256, 1024, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

is incorrect. Quoting from the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html#ixzz41qAbIC7L)

> Copies a matrix (height rows of width bytes each) from the memory area
>   pointed to by src to the memory area pointed to by dst, where kind is
>   one of cudaMemcpyHostToHost, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,
>   cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, or cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice, and specifies the
>   direction of the copy. dpitch and spitch are the widths in memory in
>   bytes of the 2D arrays pointed to by dst and src, including any
>   padding added to the end of each row. The memory areas may not
>   overlap. width must not exceed either dpitch or spitch. Calling
>   cudaMemcpy2D() with dst and src pointers that do not match the
>   direction of the copy results in an undefined behavior. cudaMemcpy2D()
>   returns an error if dpitch or spitch exceeds the maximum allowed.

So the source pitch and width to copy must be specified in *bytes*. Your host matrix has a pitch of `sizeof(float) * 256` bytes, and because the source pitch and the width of the source you will copy are the same, this means your `cudaMemcpy2D`call should look like:

```
 cudaMemcpy2D(d_arr, pitch, h_arr, 256*sizeof(float), 
                256*sizeof(float), 1024, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Comment: The [doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g32bd7a39135594788a542ae72217775c) says that `cudaMallocPitch`  also accepts the width in **bytes** so OP's `cudaMallocPitch` call is not correct

Answer (score 13):

Talonmies has already satisfactorily answered this question. Here, some further explanation that could be useful to the Community.

When accessing 2D arrays in CUDA, memory transactions are much faster if each row is properly aligned.

CUDA provides the `cudaMallocPitch` function to “pad” 2D matrix rows with extra bytes so to achieve the desired alignment. Please, refer to the “CUDA C Programming Guide”, Sections 3.2.2 and 5.3.2, for more information.

Assuming that we want to allocate a 2D padded array of floating point (single precision) elements, the syntax for `cudaMallocPitch` is the following:

```
cudaMallocPitch(&devPtr, &devPitch, Ncols * sizeof(float), Nrows);
```

where

- `devPtr` is an output pointer to float (`float *devPtr`).
- `devPitch` is a `size_t` output variable denoting the length, in bytes, of the padded row.
- `Nrows` and `Ncols` are `size_t` input variables representing the matrix size.

Recalling that C/C++ and CUDA store 2D matrices by row, `cudaMallocPitch` will allocate a memory space of size, in bytes, equal to `Nrows * pitch`. However, only the first `Ncols * sizeof(float)` bytes of each row will contain the matrix data. Accordingly, `cudaMallocPitch` consumes more memory than strictly necessary for the 2D matrix storage, but this is returned in more efficient memory accesses.
CUDA provides also the `cudaMemcpy2D` function to copy data from/to host memory space to/from device memory space allocated with `cudaMallocPitch`. Under the above hypotheses (single precision 2D matrix), the syntax is the following:

```
cudaMemcpy2D(devPtr, devPitch, hostPtr, hostPitch, Ncols * sizeof(float), Nrows, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)
```

where

- `devPtr` and `hostPtr` are input pointers to float (`float *devPtr` and `float *hostPtr`) pointing to the (source) device and (destination) host memory spaces, respectively;
- `devPitch` and `hostPitch` are `size_t` input variables denoting the length, in bytes, of the padded rows for the device and host memory spaces, respectively;
- `Nrows` and `Ncols` are `size_t` input variables representing the matrix size.

Note that `cudaMemcpy2D` allows also for pitched memory allocation on the host side. If the host memory has no pitch, then `hostPtr = Ncols * sizeof(float)`. Furthermore, `cudaMemcpy2D` is bidirectional. For the above example, we are copying data from host to device. If we want to copy data from device to host, then the above line changes to

```
cudaMemcpy2D(hostPtr, hostPitch, devPtr, devPitch, Ncols * sizeof(float), Nrows, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)
```

The access to elements of a 2D matrix allocated by `cudaMallocPitch` can be performed as in the following example:

```
int    tidx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int    tidy = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

if ((tidx < Ncols) && (tidy < Nrows))
{
    float *row_a = (float *)((char*)devPtr + tidy * pitch);
    row_a[tidx] = row_a[tidx] * tidx * tidy;
}
```

In such an example, `tidx` and `tidy` are used as column and row indices, respectively (remember that, in CUDA, `x`-threads span the columns and `y`-threads span the rows to favor coalescence). The pointer to the first element of a row is calculated by offsetting the initial pointer `devPtr` by the row length `tidy * pitch` in bytes (`char *` is a pointer to bytes and `sizeof(char)` is `1` byte), where the length of each row is computed by using the pitch information.

Below, I'm providing a fully worked example to show these concepts.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cuda.h>
#include<cuda_runtime.h>
#include<device_launch_parameters.h>
#include<conio.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE_x 16
#define BLOCKSIZE_y 16

#define Nrows 3
#define Ncols 5

/*****************/
/* CUDA MEMCHECK */
/*****************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %dn", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) { getch(); exit(code); }
    }
}

/*******************/
/* iDivUp FUNCTION */
/*******************/
int iDivUp(int hostPtr, int b){ return ((hostPtr % b) != 0) ? (hostPtr / b + 1) : (hostPtr / b); }

/******************/
/* TEST KERNEL 2D */
/******************/
__global__ void test_kernel_2D(float *devPtr, size_t pitch)
{
    int    tidx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int    tidy = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if ((tidx < Ncols) && (tidy < Nrows))
    {
        float *row_a = (float *)((char*)devPtr + tidy * pitch);
        row_a[tidx] = row_a[tidx] * tidx * tidy;
    }
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    float hostPtr[Nrows][Ncols];
    float *devPtr;
    size_t pitch;

    for (int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < Ncols; j++) {
            hostPtr[i][j] = 1.f;
            //printf("row %i column %i value %f \n", i, j, hostPtr[i][j]);
        }

    // --- 2D pitched allocation and host->device memcopy
    gpuErrchk(cudaMallocPitch(&devPtr, &pitch, Ncols * sizeof(float), Nrows));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy2D(devPtr, pitch, hostPtr, Ncols*sizeof(float), Ncols*sizeof(float), Nrows, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    dim3 gridSize(iDivUp(Ncols, BLOCKSIZE_x), iDivUp(Nrows, BLOCKSIZE_y));
    dim3 blockSize(BLOCKSIZE_y, BLOCKSIZE_x);

    test_kernel_2D << <gridSize, blockSize >> >(devPtr, pitch);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy2D(hostPtr, Ncols * sizeof(float), devPtr, pitch, Ncols * sizeof(float), Nrows, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < Ncols; j++) 
            printf("row %i column %i value %f \n", i, j, hostPtr[i][j]);

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Just want to clarify whether we really need to have cudaDeviceSynchronize() after the kernel call?

Comment: @MuneshSingh The synchronization after the kernel call is related to [CUDA error check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).

Comment: Hi @JackOLantern , thanks for the explanation. I have question: What is the float hostPtr[Nrows][Ncols]; was a Pointer i.e. float **hostPtr, dynamic array instead of the static array, why does the code fails?

Comment: in your answer, first section, there is a typo, hostPtr = Ncols * sizeof(float) has to be changed to hostPitch = Ncols * sizeof(float)