# How to access device 2D array global variable from host

Tags: cuda

I want to print d_t global 2D array variable using "printf" inside main method. But I got a compile warning saying that:

> a __device__ variable "d_t" cannot be directly read in a host function

How can I copy global 2D array variable from device to host and then print the first column of each row?

```
__device__ double *d_t;

__device__ size_t d_gridPitch;


__global__ void kernelFunc()
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    double* rowt = (double*)((char *)d_t + i * d_gridPitch);
    rowt[0] = rowt[0] + 40000;

}


int main()
{
    int size = 16;
    size_t d_pitchLoc;
    double *d_tLoc;

    cudaMallocPitch((void**)&d_tLoc, &d_pitchLoc, size * sizeof(double), size);
    cudaMemset2D(d_tLoc, d_pitchLoc, 0, size * sizeof(double), size);

    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_gridPitch, &d_pitchLoc, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_t, & d_tLoc, sizeof(d_tLoc));

    kernelFunc<<<1,size>>>();

    for(int i=0; i< size; i++){
        double* rowt = (double*)((char *)d_t + i * d_gridPitch);
        printf("%.0f, ",rowt[0]);
    }

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `cudaMemcpy2D` function is used to copy to or from a pitched allocation (i.e. created with `cudaMallocPitch`). [Here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g3a58270f6775efe56c65ac47843e7cee) is the API documentation for `cudaMemcpy2D`. If you search on this CUDA tag you will find *many* questions and answers that demonstrate proper usage, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35771430/cuda-cudamallocpitch-cudamemcpy2d-with-2d-array-error).  Use [proper CUDA error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589).

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in comments, the [`cudaMemcpy2D`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g3a58270f6775efe56c65ac47843e7cee) API is designed for exactly this task. You must allocate or statically define a host memory buffer or container to act as storage for the data from the device, and then provide the pitch of that host buffer to the `cudaMemcpy2D` call. The API handles the pitch conversion without any further intervention on the caller side.

If you replace the print loop with something like this:

```
double* h_t = new double[size * size];
cudaMemcpy2D(h_t, size * sizeof(double), d_tLoc, d_pitchLoc, 
        size * sizeof(double), size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
for(int i=0, j=0; i< size; i++){
    std::cout << h_t[i * size + j] << std::endl; 
}
```

[Note I'm using [iostream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream) here for the printing. CUDA uses a C++ compiler for compiling host code and you should prefer `iostream` functions over `cstdio` because they are less error prone and support improve diagnostics on most platforms].

You can see that the API call form is very similar to the `cudaMemset2D` call that I provided for you in your last question.